# php: sort and count instances of words in a given string

Tags: php

I need help sorting and counting instances of the words in a string.

Lets say I have a collection on words:

> happy beautiful happy lines pear gin happy lines rock happy lines pear

How could I use php to count each instance of every word in the string and output it in a loop:

```
There are $count instances of $word
```

So that the above loop would output:

> There are 4 instances of happy.
>
> There are 3 instances of lines.
>
> There are 2 instances of gin....

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use a combination of [`str_word_count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) and [`array_count_values()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php):

```
$str = 'happy beautiful happy lines pear gin happy lines rock happy lines pear ';
$words = array_count_values(str_word_count($str, 1));
print_r($words);
```

gives

```
Array
(
    [happy] => 4
    [beautiful] => 1
    [lines] => 3
    [pear] => 2
    [gin] => 1
    [rock] => 1
)
```

The `1` in `str_word_count()` makes the function return an array of all the found words.

To sort the entries, use [`arsort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php) (it preserves keys):

```
arsort($words);
print_r($words);

Array
(
    [happy] => 4
    [lines] => 3
    [pear] => 2
    [rock] => 1
    [gin] => 1
    [beautiful] => 1
)
```

Comment: How can I use this with an accent word ? Example: Épée

Comment: Amazingly simple! ;) Thanks!

Comment: @syfantid yes you said well no other answer required to look ;)

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
$words = explode(" ", "happy beautiful happy lines pear gin happy lines rock happy lines pear");
$result = array_combine($words, array_fill(0, count($words), 0));

foreach($words as $word) {
    $result[$word]++;
}

foreach($result as $word => $count) {
    echo "There are $count instances of $word.\n";
}
```

Result:

```
There are 4 instances of happy.
There are 1 instances of beautiful.
There are 3 instances of lines.
There are 2 instances of pear.
There are 1 instances of gin.
There are 1 instances of rock.
```