# PHP: str_word_count print the words and the number of the repeated words

Tags: php

I want to find tags from the last 50 posts and print them with the number of how many the tag was repeated?

so far I printed the tags. how can I print the number of "how many the tag was repeated".

```
$posts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id desc Limit 50");

while($fetch_tags = mysql_fetch_assoc($posts))
{
    $tags_array  = str_word_count($fetch_tags['tags'],1);
}

foreach($tags_array as $tag)
{
    echo $tag .'<br/>';   // ex: html</br/>php</br/> ...etc.
}
```

i want the output be like `$tag:$number<br/>`...

Comment: Yep this is a duplicate. Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2984800/171318

Comment: @showdev the problem here it's in while no normal $string otherwise your link would work..

Comment: @hek2mgl did you try it ? it's work if it's a normal string. but in while it does not

Comment: It works anywhere. In your case: `array_count_values(str_word_count($fetch_tags['tags'], 1))`. You'll need to revise your output loop as the new array is structured differently.

Comment: @AbdullahSalma I'm with showdev. However just wanted to help (as the answer I've linked is great)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the array like:

```
$posts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id desc Limit 50");
$results = array();

while($fetch_tags = mysql_fetch_assoc($posts))
{
    $tags_array  = str_word_count($fetch_tags['tags'],1);

    foreach($tags_array AS $index => $tag) {
        if ( !isset($results[$tag]) ) $results[$tag] = 1; // First occurrence
        else $results[$tag] += 1; // Add one occurrence
    }
}

// Now that we counted, print the results
foreach($results AS $tag => $number)
{
    echo "{$tag} : {$number}<br />\n";
}
```

Comment: ammm how do i test your code ? with the information I got from db ? do I put the first foreach inside the while ? i test it i shows 1 : 3 ..? i have 2 posts one with "php javascript css" and the other "php javascript"... could explain more..

Comment: Try it inside your while, just below $tags_array = str_word_count($fetch_tags['tags'],1);

Comment: i tried it shows 1 for each word... I changed the first post's tag into `php javascript css php`. now the php tags printed like {php}:{2}. **BUT** there should be three because the second post's tags are `php javascript`. look like if there is repeated tags in the same post it appear but in different post it doesn't, and it needs to be the opposite. I hope I explained my point ? can you help ?

Comment: I modified the answer, try it now.

Comment: you're my hero... thanks alot ... :)~