# How to convert array to string with both side of value

Tags: php, arrays

I have a table and in the table I have a column that shows details of uploaded files.

[image]

Like pdf, ppt, pdf.

With help of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984786/php-sort-and-count-instances-of-words-in-a-given-string) I convert my string into array.

So if I have `ppt pdf ppt doc image` it is converted into

```
Array ( [ppt] => 2 [pdf] => 1 [doc] => 1 [image] => 1 )
```

How can I convert this array into the following string?

```
2 ppt + 1 pdf + 1 doc + 1 image
```

Comment: `so it is possible that this array convert into my below string` - yes, you can do it with a simple foreach loop.  What have you tried...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it this way

```
$array=["ppt" => 2,"pdf" => 1,"doc" => 1,"image" => 1 ];

$implodable=[];
foreach($array as $k=>$v){
    $implodable[] = "$v $k";
}

echo implode(" + ", $implodable);
```

Output

```
2 ppt + 1 pdf + 1 doc + 1 image
```

Using an Array and implode, means you don't have to trim anything off the end.... :)

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0df98f4415268a80391bde3f930eaca99f39537a)

Comment: Thanks for help bro !!

Comment: Sure, it was ... simple for me.  I thought about using something fancy like `array_walk`, actually I have an idea

Answer (score 1):

**You can do this with a foreach loop:**

```
$result = null;

foreach ($array as $key => $value){ //Loops through array
    $result .= $value . ' ' . $key . ' + '; //Adds key and array to string
}

$result = substr($result, 0, -3); //Removes last 3 characters
```

Source: [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)